# Entity Framework ExecuteStoreCommand gives {"ORA-00936: missing expression"}

Tags: vb.net, oracle, entity-framework

I'm trying to run the following in a VB.NET application using Entity Framework 6 on an Oracle database:

```
mrstage.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM CB_LISTINGS WHERE ELIGIBLE={0}", eligible)
```

When it executes, I get the error: {"ORA-00936: missing expression"}

On my table, ELIGIBLE is of type VARCHAR2, and the eligible variable is a string.

If I hardcode the parameter, for example:

```
mrstage.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM CB_LISTINGS WHERE ELIGIBLE='ECB'")
```

It works fine.

I'd be very grateful if someone can offer any suggestions.

Thanks!

James

Comment: Been a while since I did Oracle, but if I remember correctly, parameters are named differently, try `:0` instead of `{0}`.

Comment: That has indeed done the trick! I had assumed that the parameter translation was handled by EntityFramework rather than the DBMS engine.

Comment: Great, I'll put it as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle parameters are named differently, use a column parameter like `:0` instead of `{0}`.

So your code is now:

```
mrstage.ExecuteStoreCommand(
    "DELETE FROM CB_LISTINGS WHERE ELIGIBLE=:0",
    eligible)
```